# iOS 13 Fonts for NSAttributedString when NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject has CoreText issues

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I use `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData` to transfer my `NSAttributedString` to `Data` and saved it to `Realm` or `UserDefaults`. Here is the extension that I implemented. It works pretty well before iOS 13

```
extension NSAttributedString {

    func toData() -> Data {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            var data = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self, requiringSecureCoding: true)
            if data == nil {
                data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)
            }
            return data!
        } else {
            return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)
        }
    }

    static func fromData(_ data: Data) -> NSAttributedString? {
        var attribute: NSAttributedString?
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            attribute = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSAttributedString.self, from: data)
        } else {
            attribute = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? NSAttributedString
        }
        return attribute
    }
}
```

I encountered some issues when I transfer the Data to `NSAttributedString` by using the `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject` method

Here is the warning that I got from the logs:

```
CoreText note: Client requested name ".PingFangSC-Light", it will get TimesNewRomanPSMT rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[UIFont systemFontOfSize:].
CoreText note: Client requested name ".PingFangSC-Medium", it will get TimesNewRomanPSMT rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[UIFont systemFontOfSize:].
```

It happens only when it's not English and the fonts that I'm using have `Light` or `Bold` or `Medium` font-weight. I know that I should use `CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage` to get the fonts on iOS 13.

But `attribute = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSAttributedString.self, from: data)` seems doesn't work as this step doesn't involve any font changes.

Here is all the sample that I made: https://gist.github.com/MrFuFuFu/8e3778d8fb5a39e9b74211619caab4d6